# Graphing on Rails 3 + dygraphs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, graph, coffeescript

I have a very large data set that I'd like to craft into a scaling, zoomable, panning graph that goes back over the course of a decade of data.  It appears that the best solution for the job is dygraphs vs other options.

I'm not opposed to other options if any meet the requirements of very high interactivity, so if'n you got someth'n else, please share...

***Notwithstanding, I have not found a solid example of using dygraphs with Rails 3 and would really appreciate seeing an example of how to tie this into a dataset very quickly or a link to an example.***

Initially I just need to throw all of the content out into the graph to see how it works out and for some analysis, so nothing super fancy's needed.

**EDIT: Just found Highstock.  Seems to be a perfect match.  In that light I'd like to modify my request to perhaps some examples of utilizing Highstock in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I can't point to any tutorials or lessons. I actually had this exact same problem a while ago, trying to do the exact same thing. My answer is that you just have to generate the HTML/dygraphs functions to plot your data.

In case you are still trying to figure this out, I have created rails app that will interactively let the user choose and plot data from any basic database schema, any database. I'm a total RoR noob, but it works pretty well and is made to be generic and dynamic, as well as add checkboxes and linear regressions to each plot. Its not finished, or fully documented  yet but you may find it helpful.

I think you can access it this way:

git clone https://bitbucket.org/zachd1_618/rails-stocks.git

or just get in contact with me if you are for some reason really interested.

I've tested it on multiple databases and different schemas, and it easily handles 50k+ points across multiple graphs.

Answer (score 1):

I see that Highstock is nice too, but you shouldn't have any problems in adapting Dygraphs to what you describe. I have not used it with Rails, but have good experiences with it on Django. The approach would be quite similar: Either you serve the dataset in a separate request, or you generate the dataset within the template layer. The latter is probably the slowest.

Comment: Thanks for that info.  Yeah, I put this on the back burner as I'd hoped to find an example and since I have other items that have been a priority before I implement that.